# Redux/React and MVC, OOP

Tags: javascript, oop, model-view-controller, reactjs, redux

Can React/Redux be thought of as an MVC framework in which also captures core Object Oriented principles? From my experience we have a fat model (the global `state/store`) and skinny controllers (`actions creators`) which `dispatch` certain actions in the right direction (`action types` used in `Reducers`) to create the new state object and hydrate our views (React).

I think React encompasses abstraction through `components` and subcomponents, inheritance/polymorphism by extending the Component class to write your own. And I feel as if `containers` enable a sense of encapsulation which hide/show certain redux functionality to/from the components.

This is how I've come to think of Redux/React architecture but am not sure this is right. Am I missing any key points or distinctions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you need OOP principles? Redux and React-redux libraries are about functional programming. Take a look at this video first - https://vimeo.com/69255635, then free online course from Redux's author - https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-the-single-immutable-state-tree

Comment: Well personally my computer science education was based around OOP. I get that the libraries are about FP, but are my analogies wrong? Am I just describing React/Redux to my liking in order to fit my base knowledge of OOP. Maybe it just doesn't matter, but I feel that my analogies have helped me understand/use the libraries "successfully".