# What kind of design pattern React Redux is using?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm using React with Redux for most of recent web app projects but I cannot answer the question which design pattern it is? It looks like an MVC but feels different.

The context is a typical React Redux application with no additional middleware and other state management libs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that this article will help [Thinking in Redux...](https://hackernoon.com/thinking-in-redux-when-all-youve-known-is-mvc-c78a74d35133)- and I'm providing a link to a previous/overlapping stackoverflow question [Redux/React and MVC, OOP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34811216/redux-react-and-mvc-oop).

TLDR;
Redux focuses on functional programming concepts and some parallels can be drawn to existing frameworks but it isn't important to get caught up on the naming/abbreviations... just really the concepts.